# Error while Dropping Duplicate Rows in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, drop, drop-duplicates

**--Table Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
ID INT, 
FirstName Varchar(100), 
LastName Varchar(100), 
Country Varchar(100) ); 

Insert into Test (FirstName,LastName,Country)values('Raj','Gupta','India'),
                                ('Raj','Gupta','India'),
                                ('Mohan','Kumar','USA'),
                                ('James','Barry','UK'),
                                ('James','Barry','UK'),
                                ('James','Barry','UK');
```

alter table Test modify column ID int primary key auto_increment;

**--To delete duplicate rows**

```
Delete * from Test where id not IN 
(select min(id) from Test 
 group by FirstName,LastName,Country
);
```

***--output error
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from Test where id not IN (select min(id) from Test group by Firs' at line 1***

Comment: There is no `Delete *` , just `delete` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete 
from Test 
where id not IN ( select min(id) 
                  from Test 
                  group by FirstName,LastName,Country 
                 );
```